# How to add Safari to my Dock?

Tags: macos, mac, dock

My Mac mini system tray (Dock) havs so many icons. However Safari's icon is not available in the Dock. I can see the application in my Applications folder.

How can I put Safari onto my Dock, so I can directly access it from my desktop itself without having to find it in my Applications folder?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is better suited for http://superuser.com and I have voted to move it there. After five people vote, your question will move automatically.

Comment: It's called the dock, not the system tray.

Answer (score 13):

Double click safari to open it. Then, when it's open, right click on it's icon on the dock (which you call the system tray), and say `keep in dock' (or options -> keep in dock on snow leopard).

Answer (score 13):

Drag-n-drop the icon from a finder window to the Dock.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is an article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2474) on the Apple website about the Dock in general, but also includes information on how to add or remove icons from the Dock.